# Apps to walk me through Frankfurt Germany

Tags: germany, tips-and-tricks, mobile-apps

Are there mobile apps for an iPhone 4 that can walk me through Frankfurt and other German places. And by *walk through*, I mean guiding me to the places I need to go, showing what trains I need to catch, buses, and so on.

I know GPS programs, basically do that, but I wanted something more "tourist", that would me show nice places, the times of buses, that would make recommendations and also in English, since I don't speak German.

Comment: The major 'walking' tourist venues are clustered along the river and along the [Zeil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeil). The city centre is very well...  central (10-15 mins walking max), is there something special an app could provide?

Comment: I search on "Stadtwanderung app bei Frankfurt" and got [an app here](http://www.outdooractive.com/en/mobile.html).  Can't vouch for it's English translator however (didn't install it).

Comment: I'm plugging two apps: Dérive app, http://deriveapp.com and the upcoming Kompl, sneak peek at http://kompl.meteor.com. I'm involved in both.

Comment: I typically use Tripadvisor city guide but they don't seem to have Frankfurt yet. Take a look at http://www.top10travelapps.com/search/frankfurt

Answer (score 1):

Try these apps, they in English. Most popular, I some used - "Ask a nomad", "Tripadvisor offline city guides", "Localscope", "Tagwhat", "Now", "Numbeo"

Answer (score 0):

For public transport information Google Maps is indispensable. It has access to bus and train timetables in every city I've been to. Do use with a bit of care of course. However it can only show you how to go somewhere if you know you want to go there. It does require data access at least at the start of your journey.

The TripAdvisor city guides are quite good at showing you what you can visit, they often provide a kind of "tour" of what's there.